MySQL upgrade from 80034 to 80035 "Still pending", so MySQL 80037 won't start
My "MySQL" instance on a dedicated server decided to update by itself. Automatic updates should be beneficial for security reasons, but in this case the Database collapsed.
A few months ago I already had this issue, and I solved it by adding the "--upgrade=MINIMAL" flag to the mysqld startup in systemd
Now the problem is back, probably even worse because of my previous fix, and I don't know how to fix it anymore.
Whenever I start the server it complains about an upgrade to version "80035" that is "still pending".
If I run "mysqld --upgrade=FORCE" or "AUTO" or "MINIMAL" I get the same message
If I run "mysqld --upgrade=NONE" it says upgrade is required so the server will stop
I tried downloading the data from the "/var/lib/mysql" folder but putting it in a MySQL 80034 it complains that the directory structure is of MySQL 80036
If I put it in a MySQL 80035 it complains that it cannot upgrade from 80035 to 80035 for the same exact reason (the update to 80035 is "Still pending", with a comical message "Server upgrade started with version 80035, but server upgrade of version 80035 is still pending.")
Error message when trying to start MySQL 80037
Does anyone out there have any idea how to fix this kind of problem? I want to really force the update, at least on the local 80035 version that should be the one that is giving trouble, but mysql seems completely stuck
Thanks a lot in advance for your time, I am honestly 100% stuck on this after days trying to fix it; other than losing data and just reinstalling MySQL with a fresh Schema I see no other options.
I even went on a tangent trying to import ibd files but the most important tables are giving me trouble on import... I guess that would be a completely separate question

Solved by downloading MySQL source code at the required version, removing sanity checks that failed due to the corruption caused by the half-update until I got a barely standing version of MySQL Server from which I could dump the data, which I used to initialize a fresh install.
